# Issue with older TV stand mounting hooks

Tags: mounting, television

I just bought a new TV that uses a smaller screw for mounting.  My TV stand has these hooks that screw onto the TV and then the TV hangs from these hooks on the stand.  If I bought smaller screws to fit the TV they wouldn't be large enough for the holes on the hooks without a washer and I'm not sure if that is a good secure way of mounting them.  I tried searching for replacement hooks with an appropriate size mounting holes but all I can find online is wall mounting which I can not do.  What is the best way to proceed from here so that I can hang my TV from the stand?

I added the mounting tag even though it says to a wall since mounting is my end goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your local hardware store and ask for help finding aluminum or bronze sleeves (bushings) like so:

[image]

They should be the same length as (or slightly shorter than) the thickness of your brackets. They'll fill the gap between your screws and the bracket holes. Also get some suitable washers to enlarge the screw heads.

Comment: That thing looks huge LOL but it would work well to do the job if a bit smaller... +

Comment: I will mark this as the answer after I have a chance to go to a hardware store and purchase some of these and try it.